# How calibrate an RGB LED to get correct color mixing

Tags: rgb, calibration, light-sensor

We are using RGB LEDs in our product and we require to emit white light to indicate a certain state. But because of the tolerance of the resistors and the LED itself it is hard to achieve the same white color in all the devices(some are reddish white, some are yellowish). We are driving the RGB leds using PWM with 255 duty cycle.

In order to solve this we decided to use a color sensor to calibrate each RGB led on the product using a color sensor(We are using http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-I2C_Color_Sensor/) . What we would like to do is to store a calibration value that corrects R, G and B (e.g. by some multiplication factor) so that mixing of colors can be achieved accurately for not just white but any color. But unfortunately color sensor channels(RGB) data and its correlation to PWM value is not straight forward from what we understand. Could anybody help us out with a solution.

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad

Comment: Is the color sensor attached to your product, or will it belong to an external piece of calibration equipment?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: We had a project about emitting white light with a CCT range of 3000-6000K using RGB LEDs. Tried a lot of RGB LEDs: cheap Chinese strips, Cree and even Osram.. Tried even 65536 steps PWM. But we got nothing. One example: We tried to drive an RGB strip with PWM and measured CCT of the mix after every single duty cycle step. When we measured it as 4200K with a calibrated chromameter, it looked "pink" compared to real 4200K white strip. After about 1.5 years of R&D, we concluded that emitting white light with RGB LEDs is nearly impossible. If you find a good solution, I'd like to hear. Good luck!

Comment: A color sensor is useless. I spent some years developing RGB white balance calibration equipment for Siemens/Osram (back when Siemens owned them -- they are Osram Licht AG now, I think.) Here's a photo of a pair of such devices used in outside display systems: http://www.infinitefactors.org/misc/images/p1000046_640x480.jpg . You won't get where you want _easily_ from where you are. In fact, if you'd have asked me, I'd have said you'd be exactly where you say you are. A _solution_ would be too involved for me to care to write here.

Comment: @Daniel obvious question was asked, with context of the end goal and steps they previously took to reach said goal...

Comment: @Passerby This question follows the format: We want to do a thing. We tried a thing. Thing didn't work. ????? Sorry not sorry, but the more I study color the more I realize that the stuff in the ?????? could get someone a PhD. Jonk knows what's up.

Comment: @Daniel the question is how to calibrate RGB LED to achieve the correct color mix.? Sorry if my post wasnt understandable.

Comment: @calcium3000 The color sensor is mounted on an external jig.

Comment: You can't get 'good' white out of RGB. It's just not possible. the CCT doesn't mean much when the CRI is 40!